# Can't run AOT code

Tags: halide

I'm currently doing the AOT tutorial and the compilation part works but when I try to build the code (that's in a separate project), that includes the compiled code, it fails to build because of the following error:

[image]

How do I resolve it?

EDIT: follow up question. I managed to compile 2 functions and when I'm trying to use them in the same project, it keeps throwing the following error:

[image]

That's just a few of the errors. So my follow up question is. Can I merge all my functions into one file or is there another way to ignore the double definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the `NoRuntime` feature in the target to remove the `halide_` functions. You still need those functions, of course, and you can use `compile_standalone_runtime()` to produce a single copy of them.

Comment: would that mean that I'd have to copy all the functions that I want to compile in AOT and put them into a single project and then call `compile_standalone_runtime()`?

Comment: Each use of `compile_to_file` will produce an AOT header/object file pair. `compile_standalone_runtime` produces an object file. Link them together with your code that uses the AOT functions. This can be tedious on Windows because you will have to make one (or more if you like) projects to produce the object files that your final project needs.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding the .obj file as one of linker's inputs